# Python recursive function for appending variable

Tags: python

I am attempting to assess a series of images in a folder for cloud coverage using OpenCV. I have determined a very simple binary threshold for whether an image contains cloud: in a subset of the image, "summit_roi", if the number of individual pixels with value < 50 is greater than 2000, the image is cloud-free (Each image is a .png file of 512h x 644w pixels with each pixel having a value between 0 and 256).

I would like to loop through the images one-by-one and return an individual value of 0 or 1 for each image where "1" is cloud-free and "0" is cloudy. Then I would like to append each individual value to a variable that, once the script has run through the folder of images, will return a single value of the total number of images in the folder with value 1 (e.g. the variable returns 52 if there are 52 cloud-free images).

I am having difficulty in writing a loop that would return this variable. Any help appreciated. Apologies if my question is too similar to previously posted questions, but I haven't found any! Here's what I have so far:

```
#loop through image_path_list to open each image
for imagePath in image_path_list:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)
    print(image.shape)

    #create ROI
    #ROI formula: roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    summit_roi = image[100:200, 250:450]
    #draw ROI rectangle on image
    #draw rectangle formula: cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(250,100), (450,200), (255,0,0), 2)

    #determine various image details
    #print('Shape of summit ROI array is', np.shape(summit_roi))
    counts = (summit_roi < 50).sum()
    print('Sum of pixels with value < 50 is', counts)

#create function to count images meeting threshold conditions
def cloud_detector(counts):   
    cloud_list = []   
    for imagePath in image_path_list:
        if counts > 2000:
            return [1]    
            cloud_list.append(cloud_detector(counts))
        else:
            return []

print(cloud_list)
```

I have tagged this post with recursion as I believe I may be missing some code where the function calls itself (and therefore is updated with each successive image), but don't understand how I can call it correctly. Again, help appreciated!

Comment: Once you do that `return [1]` or `return []`, the function is over. The `cloud_list.append` never happens, and neither does the next iteration of the loop. I'm not sure what that function is intended to do, but it's at least possible that what you're looking for is `yield` rather than `return`.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you think you need recursion here. You're already looping over all of the images. Why do you want to make a recursive call that loops over all the same images? More generally, recursion has to (a) have a base case (which your `else` might be), and (b) reduce the problem size for each recursive call (e.g., maybe something like `cloud_detector(count-2000)`), or you're just writing an infinite loop (that will fail with `RecursionError` after 1000 steps in CPython).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recursion needed; you've already done that hard parts of accessing and counting the pixels you need.  Starting here:

```
counts = (summit_roi < 50).sum()
```

Let's work both ways to get the result you want.  First, let's work with `counts` to neatly get the results for one image:

```
dark_pixel_count = (image[100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum()
```

Now, add the check against 2000 for your Boolean decision of whether there's a cloud:

```
is_cloud = (image[100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum() > 2000
```

Note how I'm adding a new clause or clarification at each step, re-naming the result.  You can do all of this with successive steps and intermediate variable names; that's good for debugging.  Some one-line computations are more "Pythonic".

`is_cloud` is a simple Boolean (`True / False`).  Next, back up and get the `image` more directly from the source.  Where we have

```
for imagePath in image_path_list:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)
    is_cloud = (image[100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum() > 2000
```

make the substitution for `image`

```
    is_cloud = (cv2.imread(imagePath, 0) [100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum() > 2000
```

Now, let's get a list of *all* the cloud detection, iterating over the input set:

```
is_cloud_list = [ (cv2.imread(imagePath, 0) [100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum() > 2000
                   for imagePath in image_path_list ]
```

This gives us a list of Booleans, one for each image.  Now, we just count how many are `True`:

```
cloud_count = [ (cv2.imread(imagePath, 0) [100:200, 250:450] < 50).sum() > 2000
                 for imagePath in image_path_list ].count(True)
```

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you, this was very well and patiently explained and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think, though I don't fully understand the intent, that this is more complex than necessary. Why not forgo the function entirely.

I suggest you simply modify:

- Remove the function.
- Precede the code with `cloud_count = 0`.
- Follow the counts declaration in the for loop with the following.

`if counts > 2000:
    cloud_count += 1`

- Modify the `print` to `print(cloud_count)`.